# d3js: Dynamically updating node objects

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a force graph with nodes representing political candidates as circles. Each circle's radius corresponds to the candidate's approval rating (a percentage). I have data over three years. It's coming from a .CSV file. I'm working in d3.js, and I'm still very new.

What I'm trying to do is dynamically update each node object such that the radius reflects the currently-selected year. Loading the graph works fine: the first year (2013) works. But, when I switch to 2012, the DOM elements don't change: they retain their 2013 values. Here are the relevant snips of code:

After opening the CSV call:

```
        data.forEach(function(d) {

            var node = {
                id: d.id,
                name: d.candidate,
                value: (parseInt(d["y"+year])),
                radius: (parseInt(d["y"+year], 10))*3,
                party: d.cand_party,
                sex: d.gender
            };
            nodes.push(node);
            });
```

And here's the update I'd like to do:

```
        d3.select(window).on("keydown", function() {
                switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
                case 37: year = Math.max(year0, year - 1); break;
                case 39: year = Math.min(year1, year + 1); break;
                }
                update ();
            });

            function update() {

            title.text(year);

            circles.transition(1500)
                .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; });
            };
```

The `update()` function is working, in that my `title` is switching to 2012, as desired. However, when I check each node's DOM info, I see that `radius` and `value` retain their 2013 values (the circles aren't changing size).

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You would need to change `radius` for each datum. It's probably easier if you store all the information to start with and when updating simply switch the attribute you consider for the radius.

Comment: Thanks, Lars. Just had the same thought. Will add an answer, in case it's useful to others. (Or better to delete? Maybe it's obvious to folks more experienced with JavaScript/d3js?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted too soon! In line with what Lars commented, I found this worked:

```
        data.forEach(function(d) {

            var node = {
                id: d.id,
                name: d.candidate,
                value: (parseInt(d["y"+year])),
                radius2014: (parseInt(d.y2014, 10))*3,
                radius2013: (parseInt(d.y2013, 10))*3,
                radius2012: (parseInt(d.y2012, 10))*3,
                party: d.cand_party,
                sex: d.gender
            };
            nodes.push(node);
            });
```

And then calling things like so:

```
            function update() {

            title.text(year);

            circles.transition(1500)
                .attr("r", function(d) { return d["radius"+year]; });
            };
```